# Page Navigation Transition not working in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have created a simple application and added Silverlight Toolkit into my project and tries the page navigation transitions using the following code. And it doesn't works. Weird.

```
<toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
    <toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
        <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
            <toolkit:SlideTransition Mode="SlideRightFadeIn"/>
        </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
        <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
            <toolkit:SlideTransition Mode="SlideLeftFadeIn"/>
        </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
    </toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
</toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>

<toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationOutTransition>
    <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition>
        <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>
            <toolkit:SlideTransition Mode="SlideRightFadeOut"/>
        </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>
        <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>
            <toolkit:SlideTransition Mode="SlideLeftFadeOut"/>
        </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>
    </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition>
</toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationOutTransition>
```

here I [attached my project](http://1drv.ms/1lRW144). can anyone please what is that weird error !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your App.xaml.cs File; try changing

```
RootFrame = new PhoneApplicationFrame();
TO
RootFrame = new TransitionFrame();
```

See if this helps.